# Multiple dialogs with ajaxExceptionHandler on the same page

Tags: primefaces, exception, dialog

I have a xhtml page with several dialogs declared within it

```
<ui:include src="/pages/dialogs/dialog1.xhtml"></ui:include>
<ui:include src="/pages/dialogs/dialog2.xhtml"></ui:include>
...
```

Dialogs are `dynamic="true"` and each dialog has ajaxExceptionHandler

```
    <p:ajaxExceptionHandler update="exceptionDialog" onexception="PF('exceptionDialog').show();" /> 
<p:dialog widgetVar="exceptionDialog" id="exceptionDialog">...</p:dialog>
```

When some dialog opens and exception occures after some action nothing happens. ExceptionDialog is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `<p:ajaxExceptionHandler>` created after dialog is included `<ui:include>` in the page and it is too early. You need it to be created when dialog shows up so you nead to create it dinamicly in managed bean. 
In each dialog do this

Delete `<p:ajaxExceptionHandler>` tag.
And add
    
    ...

```
<h:panelGroup id="ajaxExceptionHandlerPlaceholder">
</h:panelGroup>

<p:outputLabel id="exceptionMessage" value="#{pfExceptionHandler.message}" style="color: red" />

<script>
     createAjaxExceptionHandlerCommand();
</script>
</p:dialog>
```

In managed bean add this method

```
   public void createAjaxExceptionHandler() {
        AjaxExceptionHandler aeh = new AjaxExceptionHandler();
        aeh.setType( null );
        aeh.setUpdate( "exceptionMessage" );

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
        final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];
        root.visitTree( new FullVisitContext( context ), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit( VisitContext context, UIComponent component ) {
                if ( component.getId().equals( "ajaxExceptionHandlerPlaceholder" ) ) {
                    found[0] = component;
                    return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
                }
                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
            }
        } );

        found[0].getChildren().add( aeh );
    }
```